# Grabbing my face

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, faces

I am trying to separate an area of my model into a new object and getting more than I was expecting.

Here are my steps:

1. Create a mesh plane
2. rotate 90 deg on the X-axis
3. horizontal loop cut at 1/3 the height of the plane
4. 2 inset operations to give the plane a beveled look
5. add solidity modifier to give the form thickness.
6. In Edit Mode, select the inner most shape inside the inset face.

at this point the back of the form looks solid and DOES NOT appear to be part of the selection, however when I click 'P' to call the separate command I expect it to take a section of the front face of the object but it cuts clean through the object.

I wanted to take that square on the front face and make it a separate object but keep the underlying object whole.

I am following this tutorial... seems to work for him.... at 4:23 in the video.

I've tried making this card like 20 times.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rxbmpcBDIc

[image: help]

Comment: It might be helpful to users if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you apply the solidify modifier? If not you are separating a face from a plane which results in a hole.

You may need to clarify the question otherwise.

Comment: i will build it again and try that. thank you for the feedback!